# "mv" command-- file vanished into non-directory

Tags: mv

I was attempting to utilize the `mv` command to move a file onto a remote server. I ended up executing the command...

```
mv sqlreport.php myuser@mywebsite.org
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. Worse, my file seems to have disappeared. A new file, `myuser@mywebsite.org`, has appeared, but it is not a directory (In that I cannot `cd` into it).

Any tips on where my file may have gone, and how to rescue it?

Comment: You went wrong in that `mv` is not capable of moving a file to a remote location. You will need something like `curl` or `scp`.

Comment: @HalosGhost If you replace `mv` with `scp` you will end up with the same result. You will need to `scp` to `user@host.org:` at least.

Comment: @Bernhard, I did not mean to (nor do I feel that I did) imply that either `curl` or `scp` were 1:1 replacements for `mv` using the syntax the OP used. They are, however, tools that can be used for what the OP wants.

Comment: @HalosGhost I was not in the impression that you didn't know, but I thought that your post might have been interpreted like that by Austin.

Comment: Fair enough. You are certainly correct; `curl` and `scp` certainly have a different syntax than `mv`.

Comment: "Worse, my file seems to have disappeared. A new file, myuser@mywebsite.org, has appeared" What MIGHT be the content of that file? Don't you want to guess?

Comment: In linux, the `mv` command is used to rename files (as well as move them).

Comment: @RocketHazmat what would the difference be?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Well, when you "rename", you are just "moving" the file to a new one with a new name :D

Comment: The new file is not a directory? Impressive. Was the old file a directory?

Answer (score 44):

You have renamed your file to `myuser@mywebsite.org`.Try renaming it back:

```
mv myuser@mywebsite.org sqlreport.php
```

Comment: There's no need to quote the filename with the @ in it. (There wasn't when it was moved *to* that filename.)

Answer (score 9):

Your file is not vanished,You have just renamed it. You can rename it back to `sqlreport.php` using the following command
`mv myuser@mywebsite.org sqlreport.php`. To copy your file to remote host you can use the `scp` command.
`scp sqlreport.php myuser@mywebsite.org:/remote/directory/path`. If you want to copy a directory to remote host then you can use `-r` option suffix to `scp`.

Comment: And while we're at it: You need to put at least a colon at the end of the remote target (useful for copying something to a remote home directory) or scp works just like cp. Happens to me all the time and I always wonder briefly why my file isn't there.

Answer (score 4):

The key insight is that, in Unix, a filename can contain any character at all, except for '/' and the null character.  So, when you type `mv file user@host`, it moves file `file` to file `user@host`, even though the new name contains funny characters such as '@' and '.'.

(As per MvG's comment, things get a little more complex in the brave new world of Unicode but, for 8-bit character sets, the above remains true.)

Comment: Better make that “any byte at all”, since the interpretation as characters depends on locale. In some encodings, UTF-8 for example, there might even be byte combinations which don't correspond to characters.

Comment: Yep. As far as the kernel is concerned, pathnames are *arbitrary strings of bytes*, and the only bytes with any defined meaning are 0x2f (ASCII `/`, component separator) and 0x00 (end of C-string).  Defining a general mapping of these byte sequences to character sequences is entirely user space's problem.  (Some filesystems, e.g. NTFS, impose more complicated rules, coming as they do from OSes with more complicated pathname semantics.)

Comment: @Zack still, even in NTFS there's a POSIX name subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

In your case your file got renamed to myuser@mywebsite.org

Try using scp to copy the file to remote location